# participant status doesn't export

Tags: export

I just upgraded to Civi 4.6.3 yesterday. I'm running it on Drupal 7. I tried to export some participant records today, including the participant status. Everything exported fine except the participant status. It's blank for every record. Any ideas? Bug? User error? TIA - John

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have found a bug.  I tried just now on the Civi 4.6/Drupal demo site and got the same results as you with both Export Primary fields and selecting my own fields.  I would log it on JIRA.  https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

I did a quick Google search and could not find any relevant issues already logged for this.